# Simulating Serial Port with node.js without using names pipes

Tags: node.js, serial-port, simulation

I´m working on my own smart home system using some arduinos and Xbees, receiving them on a raspberry pi / mac os X with node.js via serial line connected xbee.

I was thinking about a small simulation so that i can develop without need of running hardware. The only way i know to simulate a serial line is using named pipes which would need two files, one for the input and one for the output. This would need heavy changes within my node.js code (using xbee-api module) which i would like to avoid.

Does anyone know another way to simulate a serial line communication without splitting the communication into two files? My aim would be to simply change the name for the serial port in the configuration of my main code which should than send and receive frames.

Answer (score 0):

I now decided to write my own simulator because there seems to be no other solution. I work corrently on a simulation of the serialport module for nodejs.

Comment: For anyone who is interested: I pushed a first version to github: https://github.com/solick/xbee-serialSim